# Code, split & design view tabs are missing from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working through some android developer codelabs and it states the below view should be chosen.

Click Split on the top right of Android Studio, this allows you to view both code and design. You can also click Code to view code only or click Design to view design only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYVDQ.png)

After pressing Split you should see three areas:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyTqH.png)

However, this is my view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwZ07.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am unable to carry on with the code lab as the live preview tab is needed.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I find it a bug in the codelab because they say make a no activity instead of empty activity. Here is the soltion:
Check Project Type: Ensure that you haven't created a "No Activity" project. If you select an "Empty Activity" project, a simple layout is created for you at res/layout/activity_main.xml, and when you open activity_main.xml, the Code/Split/Design tabs should be visible.

Answer (score 3):

Go To File->setting->Editor->Design Tools an check this below image
after that apply click and ok

[image: check this image]

**if not work Go To File-> invalidate cache click after automatically restart android studio**

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on Android Studio for mac and following the same tutorial. I found that the word SPLIT wasn't visible, but there were a series of icons on the top right on the same level as the MainActivity.kt tab. Click the middle one to split the screen between code and design.

[image: opening screen for empty activity on android studio for mac]

Answer (score 0):

If you select an **Empty Activity** project
[image]

a simple layout is created for you at
`res/layout/activity_main.xml`

when you select `activity_main.xml`, the **Code/Split/Design** will be shown.

I guess you might have created a "No Activity" project instead.

Guidance at Google [Hello World project.](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-first-app#1:%7E:text=Click%20the-,Empty%20Activity,-template%20to%20select). In this project, **Empty Compose Activity** should be selected.

Comment: Selecting MainActivity.kt (or anything?) in the browser pane made the button show up for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you

- Right click on a file
- Select Open in Right Split
- The code/split/design button should appear in the top right

I have flagged it with the Android Studio tutorial team, as you say you can't progress the tutorial without this workaround.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't work. If you open a `.kt` file with Right Split, the code/split/design button does not appear. If you open an .xml file with Right Split, the button does appear, but it still isn't similar to the tutorial as the 'code' option will show the raw XML whereas the image in the tutorial shows source code.

Comment: Not work for me!

Comment: it works, i'm working on jetpack compose preview