How to unhide code tab in split view (Android Studio)
while working on my project I accidently hide code tab from split view in android studio. How to unhide it?
File -> setting -> Editor -> Design Tools (I also check this setting but not solved my problem. I just want to unhide the code tab in split view so that I can code and see the design simultaneously.

Did you try these suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568428/code-split-design-view-tabs-are-missing-from-android-studio
